# How to earn high quality DoFollow backlinks?

Tags: seo

I have a personal blog regarding How to Blogging. I would like no the ideas that how do i get dofollow backlinks to my blog? Is there any fast ways to get backlinks?
Some webmaster says that edu., org, gov. Backliks are high quality. Is is true?
 I hope for your right information.

Comment: Question to vague and broad and doesn't offer any real value to the network.

Answer (score -1):

No, there are no short cuts to any channels of ethical search marketing. Hard work, commitment and a decent product or service is what it takes. Then you can earn natural backlinks.

I vote for this question to be closed.